# Unit testing a collection with equivalent object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, nunit

I'm in search of a simple way to test that a collection contains logically equivalent object (ignoring instance) in c#.

```cs
public class BarObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }
    public IEnumerable<BarObject> Bars { get; set; } = 
        new List<BarObject>() 
        { 
            new BarObject() { name = "johndoe", info = "wierdo" } 
        };
}

[TestClass]
public class FooTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDefaultInList()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        //Using NUnit
        CollectionAssert.Contains(foo.Bars.ToList(), 
            new BarObject() { name = "johndoe", info = "wierdo" }
        );
    }
}
```

The issue that I believe that I am having is that it is checking the instance of the object instead of the values within. How do I test that there is an object with specific values in an array simply without writing my own comparers?

Comment: Can you make BarObject a Record instead of a standard class?

Comment: override equality methods of your class

Comment: @Crowcoder I cannot change the type. This is a simple example of my problem and the actual object is quite complex so i can't but that is a great idea! I didn't know about that before.

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane I'm trying to avoid that as there are too many values and want a generic way to do it.

Comment: Possibly relevant [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Your use of the `TestMethod` attribute suggests that you are using VSTest rather than NUnit as you state. To give you an answer it's necessary to know for sure which you are using because the two frameworks contain subtle differences in the CollectionAssert class. I can answer if it's NUnit. :-)

Comment: @Charlie I'm using both. NUnit for some difficult assertions and vstest for the rest

Comment: When using the VS IDE, it 's possible to have a test assembly containing both types of tests. Your [TestMethod] test will be run using the vstest (mstest) framework. A [Test] test will be run by NUnit. However, I would expect you to get an error message if you try to use some class like CollectionAssert, which exists in both frameworks. That is... unless you do something to indicate the namespace you want to resolve it from. Do you have references to both test frameworks? (Note: the test framework you use is not the same as the runner under which you run tests.)

Comment: Yes i use the "using" naming for the NUnit framework. So it looks more like `NUnit.CollectionAssert`....